# Trying to update mysql using a html form and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-update

...which should normally not be too hard, but for some reason I just can't get it to work. I'm probably missing something or made a typo, I dunno, but whatever it is I can't find it.

```
include('connect-db.php');

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY orderid";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<div class="content-holder">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table border='1' cellpadding='10' id='ViewTable'>
            <tr>
            <th>Volgorde</th>
            <th>Titel</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $orderid = $row['orderid'];
                $title = $row['title'];
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="textbox" class="TextAreaTitle" name="order" value="<?=$orderid?>"></td>
                <td><?=$title?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitlink" Value="Verzenden">
    </form>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET orderid=$orderid  WHERE title=$title");
    echo "Updated!";
}
?>
```

I just pasted the entire code here to be sure. On the webpage, what you basically see if a table, with the colomns orderid and title, with all of their respective rows. the orderid's can be changed as they are a textbox. What I'm trying to achieve is that is one (or multiple) orderid's get changed, and you click on the button, then I want the orderid's to change accordingly in my database.

Thanks in advance for your help. Any questions please ask.

EDIT: I completely forgot to mention this, but what happens now when I click on the button, it returns the echo saying "Updated!" but the database doesn't actually update.

Comment: Why are you not doing any kind of success/error control in your script? Evaluate the return value of mysql_query, and use mysql_error. It will most likely alert you to an error before the title in your where clause, because – assuming it is a text value – you are missing single quotes around it. And on a second note, you should not use the old mysql extension any more, but mysqli/pdo if possible. And also you __have__ to inform yourself about SQL Injection and what to do against it.

Comment: I've recently looked up a bit about SQL injection, I just haven't implemented it in this specific script yet. Don't worry about that for now, I will definitely do that later on. This here is the main issue right now. I'll do a desperate attempt at success/error control now, then. :p

Comment: As an aside, `submit` is not a good name for an element. It will cause issues further down the road.

Comment: You made the biggest mistake- `mysql_connect ( "$host" , "$username" , "$password" )`. Don't use `mysql_` functions, use PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET orderid=$orderid  WHERE title=$title");
```

This needs to reference the `<input>` fields in your form, like this:

```
$orderid = $_POST['order'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET orderid=$orderid  WHERE title=$title");
```

You're never posting a `title` value back from the form. You need a `<input name="title" />` in your form, so add that. Otherwise it'll always use the last value from your while loop.

You need to add input validation if you're reading from $_POST. You're vulnerable to attack otherwise.

Edit: I modified a bit.

```
include('connect-db.php');

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY orderid";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<div class="content-holder">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table border='1' cellpadding='10' id='ViewTable'>
            <tr>
            <th>Volgorde</th>
            <th>Titel</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $orderid = $row['orderid'];
                $title = $row['title'];
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="textbox" class="TextAreaTitle" name="order[]" value="<?=$orderid?>"><input type="hidden" name="title[]" value="<?=$title?>"></td>
                <td><?=$title?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitlink" Value="Verzenden">
    </form>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    for ($i=count($_POST['title']); $i--;) {
        $orderid = $_POST['order'][$i];
        $title = $_POST['title'][$i];
        mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET orderid=$orderid  WHERE title=$title");
    }
    echo "Updated!";
}
?>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you want the title to be read-only, then use `<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?=$title?>" /><?=$title?>`

Comment: it still does show the echo saying "Updated!", but the database doesn't actually update. Could the problem lie within my include...?

Comment: Nah, not the include. Rather than `mysql_query` for the update, replace it with `echo` and see what comes out.

Comment: `WHERE title=$title` should have quotes around it. `WHERE title='$title'`

Answer (score 0):

if you use `name="order[]"`
it will return array and you must have to convert array into string using foreach

Answer (score -1):

sometimes it creates error of these type.it has different syntax while inserting data or retreive from database so should try all solution

mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET orderid='". $orderid ."'  WHERE title='". $title ."'");
    echo "Updated!";

Answer (score -1):

i hope its visible

mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET orderid=' " . $orderid . " ' WHERE title=' " . $title . " ' "); echo "Updated!";

Comment: The result is the same if I use this.